# Maven: Check if website is running after deployment

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a remote Tomcat server and configured maven project, that I can compile and deploy with `maven tomcat:redeploy`. However, if there are some runtime errors during application startup (e.g. application fails to connect the database) - it does not start although the deployment process was successfull.

I want to check, if the deployed website is up and running with maven (e.g. by checking the desired application URL for HTTP 200 status). How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Your web application must be having a index file which you can put in welcome file list in web.xml file. When you hit application URL, you will get to see that index page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like jUnit + [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and run those tests from Maven. Not sure if you could run that automatically after a deploy, because it takes some time to deploy and Maven does not know when the application is ready.

You could let Maven run a local Tomcat server using Cargo and run those unit tests against it.
I know those are not real unit tests, but you can use jUnit to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for checking if app is running

```
URL url = new URL("http://the.url.of.web.app:1234");
URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
urlConn.connect();
// jump over if-clause for casts
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
// do check on code; 200 is okay
```

After executing *mvn tomcat:redeploy* you can execute a [surefire test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) within special profile.